# Removing a solution platform from Configuration Manager

Tags: visual-studio

I have a solution in VS2008 containing C# and C++/CLI projects. There are 3 "solution platforms" in my solution:

- Any CPU
- Win32
- Mixed Platforms

I never want to "just build the C# ones" or "just build the C++ ones", I always want to build all projects. So the *solution platforms* metaphor is meaningless to me, I'll leave it on Mixed Platforms or whatever as long as they all build.

Now VS sometimes automatically switches the current solution platform to Any CPU (I'm not sure when or why). This means that pressing F7 will only try to build the C# projects, which is obviously no good. So I have to switch back to Mixed Platforms and try again.

So how to workaround this irritating problem? I have tried 2 ways:

1. In Configuration Manager, remove the Any CPU and Win32 solution platforms. This worked until I added a new project and Visual Studio very kindly added them back in... :/
2. In Configuration Manager, check all checkboxes for all projects in all configurations in all solution platforms. This becomes a nightmare to manage with many projects in the solution.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I doubt there's a good fix for this in VS2008, the C++ IDE's build system is fundamentally incompatible with the C# one.  That's going to change, VS2010 will also use MSBuild to build C++ projects.  The RC version is available for free, have a look.

Comment: You're probably right that there's not a good fix for this. For VS2010 I've tried the beta before but there's no way we will be able to afford the upgrade. I cobbled together a little app to parse the .sln file and remove any lines containing the "Any CPU" and "Win32" platform names. It's a dirty hack but I'd rather use this than that damn dialog any day :)

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

See the msdn:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165408.aspx

> Removing a Platform
>   If you realize that you have no need for a platform, you can remove it
>   using the Configuration Manager dialog box. This will remove all
>   solution and project settings that you configured for that combination
>   of configuration and target. To remove a platform
>
> 1. On the Build menu, click Configuration Manager.
> 2. In the Active solution platform box, select <Edit>. The Edit Solution Platforms dialog box opens.
> 3. Click the platform you want to remove, and click Remove.

Comment: Remember to click `ctrl + shift + S` to reflect changes in `.sln` file if you have it opened in another text editor.

Answer (score 12):

At least on Visual Studio 2005: After removing it from configuration manager, it is also necessary to edit .vcproj as text file and remove any references to Platform manually.

Comment: Looks the situation is the same for VS 2013

Comment: Same on VS 2017.

Comment: VS 2019 as well.

Comment: I think they've finally got this right in VS 2022!  It's now a .vcxproj file, so perhaps they took the opportunity to tidy this up.  Or maybe it was because I deleted *all* previously generated output directories and started from scratch.  Either way, it's working for me.

Comment: Still not working on VC 2022. Settings all stay in the vcxproj files. And the deleted settings are still available in Batch Build.